# Get frame of video for video filter is very slow to get. Is there any other way?

Tags: android, video, bitmap, video-processing, android-glide

I am trying to get video frame for filtering video. There are two techniques available 1) MediaMetadataRetriver and 2)FFMpegMediaMetadataRetriver but both are work slow for me.

Here is code where I am getting frame.

```
MediaMetadataRetriever metadataRetriever2;
metadataRetriever2 = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    metadataRetriever2.setDataSource(context,
            Uri.parse(trimmedVideoPath));
setRvVideoFilter(metadataRetriever2.getFrameAtTime(0, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC));
    setRvVideoFilter(metadataRetriever2.getFrameAtTime(0, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC));
    setRvVideoFilter(metadataRetriever2.getFrameAtTime(0, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC));
    setRvVideoFilter(metadataRetriever2.getFrameAtTime(0, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC));
    setRvVideoFilter(metadataRetriever2.getFrameAtTime(0, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC));
    setRvVideoFilter(metadataRetriever2.getFrameAtTime(0, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC));
    setRvVideoFilter(metadataRetriever2.getFrameAtTime(0, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC));
```

function which is adding bitmap to model and arraylist to further use in Adapter:

```
private void setRvVideoFilter(Bitmap bitmap) {
    modelVideoFrames = new ModelVideoFrames(bitmap);
    arrayList.add(modelVideoFrames);
}
```

And in RecyclerView Adapter I wrote this code:

```
RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
Glide.with(context)
            .load(arrayList.get(position).getFrameBitmap())
            .apply(requestOptions.skipMemoryCache(true))
            .apply(requestOptions.override(100, 100))
            .apply(requestOptions.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL))
            .apply(requestOptions.transform(new BitmapTransformation() {
                @Override
                protected Bitmap transform(@NonNull BitmapPool pool, @NonNull Bitmap toTransform, int outWidth, int outHeight) {
                    GPUImage gpuImage = new GPUImage(context);

                    switch (holder.getLayoutPosition()) {
                        case 0:
                            return toTransform;

                        case 1:
                            GPUImageGrayscaleFilter grayscaleFilter = new GPUImageGrayscaleFilter();
                            gpuImage.setImage(toTransform);
                            gpuImage.setFilter(grayscaleFilter);
                            return gpuImage.getBitmapWithFilterApplied();

                        case 2:
                            GPUImageGammaFilter gammaFilter = new GPUImageGammaFilter(.5f);
                            gpuImage.setImage(toTransform);
                            gpuImage.setFilter(gammaFilter);
                            return gpuImage.getBitmapWithFilterApplied();

                        case 3:
                            GPUImageSepiaFilter sepiaFilter = new GPUImageSepiaFilter(.05f);
                            gpuImage.setImage(toTransform);
                            gpuImage.setFilter(sepiaFilter);
                            return gpuImage.getBitmapWithFilterApplied();

                        case 4:
                            GPUImageContrastFilter contrastFilter = new GPUImageContrastFilter(.05f);
                            gpuImage.setImage(toTransform);
                            gpuImage.setFilter(contrastFilter);
                            return gpuImage.getBitmapWithFilterApplied();

                        case 5:
                            GPUImageColorInvertFilter colorInvertFilter = new GPUImageColorInvertFilter();
                            gpuImage.setImage(toTransform);
                            gpuImage.setFilter(colorInvertFilter);
                            return gpuImage.getBitmapWithFilterApplied();

                        case 6:
                            GPUImageVignetteFilter vignetteFilter = new GPUImageVignetteFilter();
                            gpuImage.setImage(toTransform);
                            gpuImage.setFilter(vignetteFilter);
                            return gpuImage.getBitmapWithFilterApplied();

                        default:
                            return toTransform;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void updateDiskCacheKey(MessageDigest messageDigest) {

                }
            }))
            .into(holder.ivFrame);
```

You can see that I am also processing Glide bitmap for showing filters. But big problem is that metadataRetriever2.getFrameAtTime(0, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC) is very slow. I was also tried to compress metadataRetriever2.getFrameAtTime(0, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC) into another Bitmap but it causes bitmap already recycled problem. So need to find some good solution.

Comment: any solution ??